# bash scripting: combine var=$(...) and var=${var%%...} lines?

Tags: linux, bash

Is it possible and, if yes, how to convert the following expression to one-liner?

```
DEV=$(lsblk -no KNAME,MODEL | grep 'ModelNAME')
DEV=${DEV%%'ModelNAME'}
```

Simple `DEV=${(lsblk -no KNAME,MODEL | grep 'ModelNAME')%%'ModelNAME'}` doesn't work

Comment: Correct, it doesn't. No, you can't arbitrarily combine parameter expansions in bash.

Comment: You can write a one-line command that does the same thing if you really need to though. You can also replace the newline with a `;` if you just want them on one visual line. What's the real goal here?

Comment: What's the output of `lsblk -no KNAME,MODEL | grep 'ModelNAME'`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. it outputs smth. like `sda     DEVICE_MODEL`, but I need only `sda`: find device node by its model

Comment: Ahh; I misread what you were trying to do. Taking the first field is easy.

Comment: BTW, all-caps names are reserved for variables special to the system or the shell; see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zsh allows you to combine parameter expansions. Bash does not.

For either bash or POSIX sh (both of which support this particular parameter expansion), you'll need to do this as two separate commands.

---

That said, there *are* other options available. For instance:

```
# tell awk to print first field and exit on a match
dev=$(lsblk -no KNAME,MODEL | awk '/ModelNAME/ { print $1; exit }')
```

...or, even easier (but requiring bash or another modern ksh derivative):

```
# read first field of first line returned by grep; _ is a placeholder for other fields
read -r dev _ < <(lsblk -no KNAME,MODEL | grep -e ModelNAME)
```